# Deduping and Merging missing

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I am brand new to CiviCRM and trying to clean up a very messy database.  I read the user guide for deduping and merging, and it made it seem like this is a built in feature I should find under contacts, but I do not have that option?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CMS (e.g. drupal/wordpress) permission for `CiviCRM: merge duplicate contacts` and you also need "Delete contacts" permission. Does your user account have those permissions?

Also try it with a search for contacts, and then from the Actions dropdown on the results page there is an option to merge contacts.

Comment: Thanks!  I am an administrator so do have both those permissions on my account, but I still don't see the menu option "Contacts > Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts".  I was able to see the merge contacts options from the search results page.

Comment: Ok interesting. If you directly visit `/civicrm/contact/deduperules` and you're able to see it, then possibly someone has just removed the menu entry. You can check that at Administer - Customize - Navigation.

Comment: So I am able to see the rules when I go directly to that url.  When I go to the navigation I see the find and merge duplicates listed under contacts, but it still doesn't show in my menu. Very strange - can I share an image on here?

Comment: Figured it out - the permission on the menu item had 2 Civi permissions using the OR operator.  When I switched it to AND operator, I can now see the "Find and Merge Duplicates" menu item!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Although that sounds backwards doesn't it? If you can see it with AND you should see it with OR. Maybe saving it cleared a cache glitch?